# Split a list every n times and always skip one row

Tags: list-manipulation

another question:

I have a very long Excel data sheet of z-values.
I converted the Excel sheet into CSV. to make it less heavy on calculation time.

The data is divided into packs of $197\times197$.
After every pack there is a row with only zeros to divide the packs.
For every block, I would like to plot a contour plot. 
Therefore I need to extract the individual blocks.

Something like: 
Split at every 197*197 Element, but skip 1*197 Element after each split (row for separation)
How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not `Import[]`, delete the zero rows, and use `Partition[]`?

Comment: How do you delete the zero rows ?

Comment: Have you seen `DeleteCases[]`?

Comment: Thanks. But the data is given as one long list {{-----}} so I do not want to delete all zeors.

Comment: You can use `DeleteCases[]` to delete an entire row; however, if your data has a legitimate row of zeros as opposed to just being a separator, then you should have chosen a better separator.

Comment: Would `Most/@Partition[yourList,197]` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`SequenceCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html), which lets you specify a replacement rule for each sequence it finds, so the delimiting zeros can be dropped that way. I'll construct a `testList` with a smaller number of rows and columns, then apply the splitting:

```
nRow = 3;
nCol = 5;
block = RandomReal[10,{nRow,nCol}];
testList = Flatten[Riffle[block, Table[{zeros}, nRow]]]

(*
==> {4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1.14841, 7.57119, 1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605, 5.91062, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
*)

SequenceCases[testList, 
  {x : Except[Repeated[0, {nRow}]] .., Repeated[0, {nRow}]} :> {x}]

(*
==> {{4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372}, 
      {1.14841, 7.57119, 1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982}, 
      {7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605, 5.91062}}
*)
```

In the search pattern for `SequenceCases`, the zeros are assumed to occur at the end of a sequence in which the preceding elements are *not* sequences of `nRow` zeros. These elements are labeled `x` and collected in `{x}` using the rule `:>`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Jens' data

```
list =
  {4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1.14841, 7.57119, 1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605, 5.91062, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

`SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3) seems to be custom-tailored for this task

```
SequenceSplit[list, {0}]
```

{{4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372}, {1.14841, 7.57119,
1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982}, {7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605,
5.91062}}

With `SequenceCases` we can get the same result:

```
SequenceCases[list, {Except[0] ..}]
```

{{4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372}, {1.14841, 7.57119,
1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982}, {7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605,
5.91062}}

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing Jens' data and using `Split`:

```
list =
  {4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1.14841, 7.57119, 1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605, 5.91062, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

Most /@ Cases[{_, __}]@Split[list, # =!= 0 &]

(*{{4.41795, 1.96463, 2.73945, 9.01363, 8.49372},
   {1.14841, 7.57119, 1.01441, 7.9697, 4.21982}, 
   {7.75255, 0.431971, 2.10869, 8.60605, 5.91062}}*)
```